# Callback inside of an event listener for window is not working

Tags: javascript, call, apply, iife

```
(function(w,d,u){
    var k = function(cb){
        window.addEventListener('scroll',function(cb){
            var scrll = this.scrollY;
            if(cb){ 
                cb.call(this,scrll);
            }
        },false);
    };
    return (window.scrollex=k);
})(this,document);
```

When I try running this it does not work at all. I keep getting undefined is not a function, why is this? Does it have to do with something of it being inside of the eventListener? Or that I passed the argument inside of the function? It's crazy I've used this many of times just seem to be having problems with it now inside of an eventListener.

Can anyone enlighten me on this issue?

**Real life Example**

```
scrollr('element',{
  max:500,
  min:400,
  swing:50,
  name:"custom_event",
  dir:"left",
  trigger:"mousemove || scroll"
 },function(t,a,c){
    //t returns an object
    //a returns the current position of the trigger if it is a mousemove or scroll
    //c returns a boolean, which is if the element is inView of the viewport
  });
```

Comment: cb would be the event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(cb){  <--cb is an event object
```

get rid of the variable

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
```

============

Based on your comments, I do not think you need call

```
cb.call(this,scrll);
```

just do

```
cb.(scrll);
```

Comment: Ok I'll try it but I've had issues without as well...scratch that it worked. It seems to give me issues inside my actual IIFE code, so I may have to do some more debugging.

Comment: The usage of what I show is not exactly what you see. I'll give you a real example of it.

Comment: and how does that apply to the code, it does not match up

Comment: of course it doesn't match lol. I wrote a small example to get my point across to figure out why the call was not working inside the eventListener. That is it. But I wrote the actual real life example for you since you didn't want me to use call. Or didn't know why i was using it.